# Python write to SQL Server not keeping rows

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a script I'm running that makes API calls, then writes the data to a database.

I am connecting to the database using this code (SQLAlchemy)

```
engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{sql_user}:{sql_password}@{sql_server}/{sql_database}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
conn = engine.connect()
cursor = conn.connection.cursor()
```

Because I'm writing to different tables depending on the API call, I wanted to make a function that was generic enough to allow me write the data, no matter the format. Also to note, I do not own / did not create the SQL Server. Despite using SSMS, there are no primary keys in any of the tables, so I have a JSON file that stores the columns that should be treated as keys.

Before writing the data to the server, I am checking to see if the data already exists using this code. If no row is found, it returns none.

```
find_query_string = f'SELECT * FROM [{table_name}] WHERE '
conditions = ' AND '.join([f'{col} = ?' for col in primary_key])
find_query_string += conditions
values = tuple([row_data[col] for col in primary_key])
print(find_query_string, values)
## SELECT * FROM [Timesheets] WHERE Id = ? AND UserId = ? (162019876, 1225205)
existing_row = cursor.execute(find_query_string, values).fetchone()
print(existing_row)
## None
```

To write the rows, I am using this code:

```
placeholder = ','.join(['?' for _ in range(len(columnn_mappings))])
insert_string = f'INSERT INTO [{table_name}] VALUES ({placeholder})'
insert_values = tuple(row_data.values())

print(insert_string, insert_values )
## INSERT INTO [Timesheets] VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) (162019876, 1225205, 15000169, '2024-01-23T07:55:00-08:00', '2024-01-23T11:55:42-08:00', Decimal('4.01'), '2024-01-23', -8, 'tsPT', 'regular', 'Kiosk (Surgery Ward)', 'False', 0, 'Forgot to clock out, Left at 5p on 1/22/23\nClocked in at 7:55a 1/23/24', Timestamp('2024-01-24 16:10:30+0000', tz='UTC'), 1225205)
cursor.execute(insert_string, insert_values )
conn.commit()
```

After writing, I am running the same query to find the data. Here is my problem. after checking for the existing row again, I am getting valid results.

```
existing_row = cursor.execute(find_query_string, values).fetchone()
print(existing_row)
## (162019876, 1225205, 15000169, '2024-01-23T07:55:00-08:00', '2024-01-23T11:55:42-08:00', Decimal('4.01'), '2024-01-23', -8, 'tsPT', 'regular', 'Kiosk (Surgery Ward)', 'False', 0, 'Forgot to clock out, Left at 5p on 1/22/23\nClocked in at 7:55a 1/23/24', datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 16, 10, 30), 1225205)
```

However, when I go into the database, that row isn't there. so why is my second "existing_row" returning data? Why is the database not keeping the data? I have already checked the SQL logs and there are no errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8zs7.png

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE (like) application, it doesn't have databases. What database engine are you using?

Comment: Assuming you have verified that you are querying the exact same database (you would be surprised how many people connect to one database in code and another in SSMS), then if the rows aren't appearing the most likely reason is that you are not committing your transaction.

Comment: i checked that too. i did a quick cursor.execute(f"select * from [{table_name}]") and returned my 250K results expected. i even made the "find_query_string" a variable so that i could ensure everything was exactly the same. im calling conn.commit() but is it possible its just not committing?

Comment: Through your application, using the same connection you are testing with, run `cursor.execute(f"select @@servername") and read out the result. Make sure it matches the server name you're specifying in your connection.

Comment: Obligatory reference to [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/). Instead of building T-SQL queries on the fly by concatenating query segments with tainted (untrusted) user data you really should be using parameterized queries. SQLAlchemy has a whole SQL Expressions subsystem to help you do this properly. Failing to do things properly means that one day you'll find a new user named `Robert'); DROP TABLE Users;--` and that will be a sad day.